# Oriented bounding box defined by angle of orientation

Tags: c++, matlab, geometry

I know how to find minimum bounding box using regionprops() in Matlab and boundingRect() using OpenCV. How to find a bounding box of points (not minimum bounding box) given the angle of orientation? For example in image below where the line is the major axis of the rectangle.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are many possible solutions. I'll mention three of these:

1. rotate all points so that the red line becomes parallel to the x (or y) axis; then, find the minimum axis oriented bounding box of transformed points; then, rotate back the box to find the desired one.
2. find the projection of every point on the red line and on a blue line (perpendicular to the red one), storing minimum and maximum values per coordinate.
3. find the distance of all points from the red line; then, with some consideration you should easily find two coords of the box; then you can repeat the computation taking a line perpendicular to the red one to find the missing two coords for the box

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the points such that axis matches with the x-axis or y-axis. Find the bounding box of the transformed points and transform the bounding box back to original space by inverse transform.
Details of transformation :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)
You can find the bounding box of transformed points like this.

```
double xmin = 1e+37,ymin = 1e+37;
double xmax = -1e+37,ymax = -1e+37;
for(size_t i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i)
{
  if( x[i] >= xmin ) xmin = x[i];
  if( y[i] >= ymin ) ymin = y[i];
  if( x[i] <= xmax ) xmax = x[i];
  if( y[i] <= ymax ) ymax = y[i];
}
```

You can replace 1e+37 with any large number or you use the BIG FLOAT

More details of oriented bounding box implementation of Stefan Gottschalk idea can also be found at this  blog [Oriented bounding box](http://jamesgregson.blogspot.com/2011/03/latex-test.html)